# Iterativly apply opperation to groups of rows with the same value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, physics

This is a bit of a weird one, I am trying to gate data based on if:

1) values in column of are in a certain range of numbers AND

2) other rows in the same group as the first one also have a different range of numbers

So to clarify, I have a column of data 'tof' and another column called 'id' that groups the rows together as being in the same event. I want to compare rows from the same event (same id), seeing if one of the rows has tof in a certain range, and one of the *other rows* has tof in a different range. If that is the case, I want to keep all rows with that id, and if it isn't, I want to throw out those rows.

```
                tof        id
9         2004847.0      10.0
10        2066116.0      10.0
11        5441996.0      10.0
12        5642443.0      10.0
17        1979815.0      15.0
18        1992399.0      15.0
19        2008208.0      15.0
20        2098060.0      15.0
21        3980280.0      15.0
```

I would store the ranges like this:

```
                           min 1  , max 1 , min 2 , max2 
channelBounds = np.array([[2000000,3000000,5000000,6000000],
                          [1000000,2000000,4000000,5000000]])
```

Where the first two numbers in each row are the min and max of one of the rows of data, and the second two are the min and max of another row of data with the same id. Hopefully, I'd be able to iterate over multiple sets of bounds, as shown.

For example, with the above data and constraints, row 9 and row 11 fit within the first constraint (9 is between 2000000 and 3000000 and 11 is between 5000000 and 6000000) so I would keep rows with id 10, but none of the rows with id 15 fit with either constraint (no two rows with id 15 have values that satisfy both ranges of constraints at the same time), so it would drop rows with id 15.

The idea with the two lines of constraints is so that multiple gates can be applied at the same time, and id sets that satisfy any of the sets listed will be kept.

I can see how to do this by iterating over the rows directly, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient (like vectorized) way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what the ranges are from `channelBounds`? Also please add the expected output

Comment: So the `channelBounds` has the same number of rows as the number of `id`?

Comment: So there has to be at least two rows for each group that fall within the two ranges?

Comment: Yeah, there have to be two different rows that fall between the different ranges in each id. See my edit for clarification with the given data

Comment: When to use the first row of channelBounds and when to use the other row of channelBounds?

Comment: @ScottBoston they are both like "or" statements. I want to keep groups with the same id if it satisfies the first row of channelBounds or the second row. ideally, id have any number of rows

Comment: `df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: sum((~pd.cut(x['tof'], bins=i).isna().any() for i in channelBounds)).astype(bool))`  Probably should test this with more robust dataset.   It appears that Group ID 15 will satisfy ChannelBound second record.

Comment: And this isn't a vectorized approach.  it is still looping

Comment: @ScottBoston It gave the error ```ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([20000, 30000, 30000, 40000]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg```

Comment: Yes, your channelBound has a duplicate edge 30000 and 30000, you can't have that using pd.cut.

Comment: @ScottBoston Right you are, but now it just returns an empty dataframe.